# Sql Azure - Unexplained locking

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We have a console app running on our server which generates reports according to a schedule.

Frequently, the processing gets blocked by a sql lock, which can last for several minutes.

I can't determine what is causing the locking, even with the use of the dynamic management views.

E.g.

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

gives:

[image]

Row 1 is the query that is being blocked. Row 2 is the query I used to generate the result.  There doesn't appear to be any other active queries that could be blocking.

This is causing significant issues in production, and I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

Can anyone suggest how I can try and get to the bottom of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at `sys.dm_tran_locks` if the issue is locking related. The DMV `sys.dm_exec_requests` only tells you which requests are blocking & the last wait type. The details are available in other related DMVs.

Below whitepaper named "*Troubleshooting Performance Problems in SQL Server 2008*" has all the troubleshooting steps:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd672789(v=sql.100).aspx